# trying to predict the salary the of person when i submit the button but getting an page not found

Tags: python, flask, http-status-code-404

```
        from flask import  Flask,redirect,url_for,request,render_template
        import numpy as np
        import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
        import pandas as pd



        app=Flask(__name__)


        def login():
            dataset = pd.read_csv('D:\\Salary_Data.csv')
            X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
            y = dataset.iloc[:, 1].values

            # Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
            from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
            X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=1 / 3, random_state=0)


            from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression


            def generate_prediction(input):
             regressor = LinearRegression()
             regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)
             y_pred = regressor.predict(input)
             return y_pred

            @app.route('/')
            def home():
                return render_template('login.html')

            @app.route('/get_price', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
            def get_price():

                input = request.form
                input = np.array(list(input.values()))
                price = generate_prediction(input)
                return " The price is {}".format(price)



        if __name__ == '__main__':
            app.run(debug=True)

    login.html

        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>Title</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form action=" http://127.0.0.1:5000/get_price" method="POST">
            <p>Enter Name:</p>
            <p>Years of Experience <input type="text" name="t1"/></p>
            <p>Salary <input type="text" name="t2"/></p>
            <p><input type="submit" value="submit"/></p>
            </form>
        </body>


        </html>
```

I'm trying to predict the salary of a person by using the machine learning algorithm linear regression and trying to give input from an HTML page and submit the button through the login. The HTML page I am getting throws a "404: page not found" exception.

What's the wrong with the code?

Comment: Did you try `<form action=" http://localhost:5000/get_price" method="POST">` ?

Comment: yes i tried did not work

Comment: Did you check the Flask project structure? See http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/tutorial/layout/

Comment: login.html page is under templates folder layout is correct

Comment: Are you able to check the endpoint `http://localhost:5000/get_price` using a tool like postman?

Comment: able to open the page with an exception 404

Comment: Let me make sure I understand. You  did HTTP POST to http://localhost:5000/get_price and got a response back?

Comment: no, I did not get back the response, HTML page itself not displayed.

Comment: I ran the application.py file and opened the URL =http://127.0.0.1:5000/get_price it through an error 404 page not found

Comment: It looks like (based on the code you have pasted) that `get_price` is nested under `login`. Am I right?

Comment: yes it is nested under login

Comment: So it is a "private" function that can be called ONLY from login.

Comment: sorry get_price() is not nested under login() function

Comment: So please edit the code in order to reflect it. As for now it looks like a nested function

Comment: ok i will do it

Comment: So the question is why HTTP GET|POST to /get_price return 404. Are we on the same page here?

Comment: thank you it worked after changing

Answer (score 0):

Your indentations are wrong. - If you're going to put the `@app.route` decorated function as a virtual function - nested function; then that code will execute once the `login` function is called.

Hence you don't have any registered routes. - Bring your routes out of the function.

As a side note and suggestion; please, do follow [PEP8 - Coding Style Guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: @indu you're welcome; if it's the correct answer don't forget to mark it as the answer.